# Unable to use std::apply on user-defined types

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, stdapply

While implementing a `compressed_tuple` class for some project I'm working on, I ran into the following issue: I can't seem to pass instances of this type to std::apply, even though this should be possible according to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply.

I managed to reproduce the issue quite easily, using the following fragment ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hh1GoqMEY)):

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(int a) : a{ a } {}

    auto &get_a() const { return a; }
    auto &get_a() { return a; }

private:
    int a;
};

namespace std {

template<>
struct tuple_size<Foo> {
    constexpr static auto value = 1;
};

template<>
struct tuple_element<0, Foo> {
    using type = int;
};

template<size_t I>
constexpr auto get(Foo &t) -> int & {
    return t.get_a();
}

template<size_t I>
constexpr auto get(const Foo &t) -> const int & {
    return t.get_a();
}

template<size_t I>
constexpr auto get(Foo &&t) -> int && {
    return std::move(t.get_a());
}

template<size_t I>
constexpr auto get(const Foo &&t) -> const int && {
    return move(t.get_a());
}

} // namespace std

auto foo = Foo{ 1 };
auto f = [](int) { return 2; };

auto result = std::apply(f, foo);
```

When I try to compile this piece of code, it seems that it cannot find the `std::get` overloads that I have defined, even though they should perfectly match. Instead, it tries to match all of the other overloads (std::get(pair<T, U>), std::get(array<...>), etc.), while not even mentioning my overloads. I get consistent errors in all three major compilers (MSVC, Clang, GCC).

**So my question is whether this is expected behavior and it's simply not possible to use `std::apply` with user-defined types? And is there a work-around?**

Comment: You have undefined behavior.  You are not allowed to add function overloads to `std`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: @NathanOliver, you're right. It seems that I don't fully understand the rules regarding extending the std namespace. I always assumed you were not allowed to add new entities, but were allowed to overload existing ones. Apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So my question is whether this is expected behavior and it's simply
> not possible to use std::apply with user-defined types?

No, there is currently no way.

In libstdc++, libc++, and MSVC-STL implementations, `std::apply` uses `std::get` internally instead of unqualified `get`, since users are prohibited from defining `get` under `namespace std`, it is impossible to apply `std::apply` to user-defined types.

You may ask, in [[tuple.creation]](https://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#creation-11), the standard describes `tuple_cat` as follows:

> [*Note 1*: An implementation can support additional types in the
> template parameter pack `Tuples` that support the `tuple`-like protocol,
> such as `pair` and `array`. — end note]

Does this indicate that other `tuple` utility functions such as `std::apply` should support user-defined `tuple`-like types?

Note that in particular, the term "`tuple`-like" has no concrete definition at
this point of time. This was intentionally left C++ committee to make this gap
being filled by a future proposal. There exists a proposal that is
going to start improving this matter, see [P2165R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r3.pdf).

---

> And is there a work-around?

Before P2165 is adopted, unfortunately, you may have to implement your own `apply` and use non-qualified `get`.

Comment: It might be that the first link you posted has updated since last year, but now I don't see any `std::` qualification before `get`. Still there is the question, whether the stdlib-providers have applied this as well.

Comment: @davidhigh https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4948

Comment: Thanks, this explains the omission of `std::` before `get`. Anyways, it doesn't seem to work for any compiler: (https://godbolt.org/z/noo5hb8Pe)[https://godbolt.org/z/noo5hb8Pe]

Comment: That's just an *editorial* fix. Since P2165 has not been adopted, the standard still does not require support for user-defined tuple-like types.

Answer (score 1):

The question has throughly been answered by @康桓瑋. I'm going to post some more details on how to provide a workaround.

First, here is a generic C++20 `apply` function:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<functional>

namespace my
{
    constexpr decltype(auto) apply(auto&& function, auto&& tuple)
    {
        return []<size_t ... I>(auto && function, auto && tuple, std::index_sequence<I...>)
        {
            using std::get;
            return std::invoke(std::forward<decltype(function)>(function)
                             , get<I>(std::forward<decltype(tuple)>(tuple)) ...);
        }(std::forward<decltype(function)>(function)
        , std::forward<decltype(tuple)>(tuple)
        , std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(tuple)> > >{});
    }
} //namespace my
```

The own namespace is useful so that the custom apply does not interfere with the std-version. The unqualified call to `get` means (quoting @Quuxplusone from his [blog](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2022/04/14/another-reason-for-the-poison-pill/), which gives the best explanation I encountered so far):

> An unqualified call using the two-step, like using my::xyzzy;
> xyzzy(t), indicates, “I know one way to xyzzy whatever this thing may
> be, but T itself might know a better way. If T has an opinion, you
> should trust T over me.”

You can then roll out your own tuple-like class,

```
struct my_tuple
{
    std::tuple<int,int> t;   
};

template<size_t I>
auto get(my_tuple t)
{
    return std::get<I>(t.t);
}

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct tuple_size<my_tuple>
    {
        static constexpr size_t value = 2;
    };
}
```

With the overload of `get()` and the specialization of `std::tuple_size`, the apply function then works as expected. Moreover, you can plug in any compliant std-type:

```
int main()
{
    auto test = [](auto ... x) { return 1; };

    my::apply(test, my_tuple{});
    my::apply(test, std::tuple<int,double>{});    
    my::apply(test, std::pair<int,double>{});    
    my::apply(test, std::array<std::string,10>{});    
}
```

[DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33a9373b3827d991)